# Rule does not log X-Forwarded-For environment variable

Tags: apache, owasp

The Apache web server is logging `X-Forwarded-For` environment variable as expected, but I have an Owasp rule where I'm trying to log this environment variable value too but without luck so far.

Here's my rule:

```
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "(?i:(?:select \* from|select\*from|load_file|sleep\())" "phase:2,capture,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,block,deny,status:510,msg:'IP: %{REMOTE_ADDR} %{X-Forwarded-For} SQL injection and other data/structure manipulation attempts',id:'9900002',tag:'WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION',logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.id}-%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+1,setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:'tx.%{tx.msg}-WEB_ATTACK/SQLI-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}'"
```

Is it possible to log `X-Forwarded-For` environment variable? If it is possible, which is the correct syntax? because `%{X-Forwarded-For}` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For
```

To me, it seems that `X-Forwarded-For` is not an environment variable, but a request header.

In some environments, each header is automatically converted to an environment variable, in the form HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. However, it seems that in ModSecurity you can simply retrieve the request header.